# Why isn't my association object id being populated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my Rails app, I have two models, `Estimate` and `Client`, which both have a `belongs_to` relationship to `State` (as in U.S. states).

If I create a simple hash like this:

```
properties = {:state => State.first}
```

... I can build a Client in the Rails console like this:

```
c = Client.new(properties)
```

... and it shows up with a `state_id` of `1`, as expected.

**However**, if I try the same with an Estimate, like this:

```
e = Estimate.new(properties)
```

... **it never sets the `state_id`**, so I can't save the association.

The tables for `Estimate` and `Client` have identical `state_id` columns (`int 11`). The association is the same. The `State` object is the same.

What could be causing this difference?

### Update

This issue was `attr_accessible` as Misha pointed out.  Another symptom we discovered was that `Estimate.state = State.first` returned `NoMethodError: undefined method state=`

Comment: Have you set `attr_accessible` in your `Estimate` model? If so, `state` may not be accessible and can only be set like this: `e = Estimate.new` and `e.state = State.first`.

Comment: @mischa That was the issue.  Thanks!  Make it an official answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Added it as an answer... Glad your problem is solved.

Comment: @user593877: `state=` is an instance method, not a class method. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set `attr_accessible` in your `Estimate` model? If so, `state` may not be accessible and can only be set like this:

```
e = Estimate.new
e.state = State.first
```

### Update

Note that `state=` is an instance method, not a class method.

This **does not** work:

```
Estimate.state = State.first
```

This **does** work:

```
e = Estimate.new
e.state = State.first
```